# Is it possible to unistall the dependency package but not the actual package?

Tags: redhat, rpm

Use case:
**package A**
Requires: package B ( B doesn't require A)

$ yum remove package B
will remove package A too

Is there any way to avoid uninstalling package A,modifying somehow the spec file?

Comment: Genuinely interested, why would you want package A without package B if A requires B?

Comment: Yes its very rare use case.
Generally I have a script that invokes puppet modules, each puppet module is a different rpm as it 's the script. The script requires all the rpms of puppet modules and the use case is if I uninstall a puppet module I dont want the script to be removed  too.

Comment: You may want to clean up that explanation. So your problem here is really that you are storing puppet modules inside rpms, that you made them dependencies of an rpm with a script inside, and that you made an rpm for a script.

Comment: Looking at your question and comments: you can use `rpm --force -e <pkg>`...

Answer (score 0):

`yum` and `dnf` sit on top of `rpm` as an interface. You can force `rpm` directly to erase the RPM.

*However*, it is probably *not* the right thing to do and can easily lead you to headaches down the road, unless you *very* specifically know what you are doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

From comments I assume you know what you are doing:

```
rpm -e --nodeps <pkg>
```

Other readers: please handle this carefuly as you may shot yourself in your own leg.

Comment: Sure, but I was wondering if there is way, doing it inside spec file.